# Generate a random frame number between 640 and 700 - AS 2

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I want that my button randomly goes to any frame between the frames 640 and 700 ?

This my code :

```
on (press){

    gotoAndPlay(random(700)+641);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can generate a random number between 0 and 60 and then add 640 :

```
var frame:Number;

on (press){

    frame = Math.floor(Math.random() * 61) + 640; 
    gotoAndPlay(frame);

}
```

Hope that can help.